# Count origin destination within polygon

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap

I have data that is XY coordinates (both origin and destination) in the CSV file. (example below, the last two-column is destination point)

[image]

Then, I want to count the number of points that start from polygon 1 (origin polygon) to polygon 2 (destination polygon) which is an administrative boundary.

I'm using ArcMap.

I would like to create a table like this below (just for example).
[image]

Comment: Please share a sample of your CSV. It's hard to find out what you are trying to do. What have you tried so far?

Comment: If you wish to also ask about QGIS, ArcGIS Pro or another GIS software then please do so in separate questions.

Comment: Please edit your question to include a couple of images of your polygon data and how your points plot on this. Also confirm what @PolyGeo is asking.